# create an Object with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-5

I have this Object

```
  var p = 
  [
    { role: 'elite', web: [{ "_id": "55555555ffffff000010200a","name": 'web A' }] },
    { role: 'elite', web: [{ "_id": "55555555ffffff000010200b","name": 'web B' }] },
    { role: 'write', web: [{ "_id": "55555555ffffff000010200c","name": 'web C' }] },
    { role: 'write', web: [{ "_id": "55555555ffffff000010200a","name": 'web A' }] },
    { role: 'view',  web: [{ "_id": "55555555ffffff000010200a","name":  'web A' }] }
  ];
```

And I Want populate an array if the role is the same.
Like this:

```
p = 
[
    {   role:'elite',
        web: [{     "_id": "55555555ffffff000010200a",
                    "name": 'web A',
                    "_id": "55555555ffffff000010200b",
                    "name": 'web B'}]
    },
    {   role:'write',
        write: [{   "_id": "55555555ffffff000010200c",
                    "name": 'web C',
                    "_id": "55555555ffffff000010200a",
                    "name": 'web A'}]
    },
    {   role:'view',
        view: [{    "_id": "55555555ffffff000010200a",
                    "name": 'web A'}]
    }
]
```

I did try with foreach or object methods, but i don't know how can i Check if the Object has a particular role then push or create in web Array inside object

Comment: I fixed the misplaced quote marks, but the OP's goign to have to actually structure the data properly, himself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var p = 
    [
        { role: 'elite', web: [{ "_id": "55555555ffffff000010200a","name": 'web A' }] },
        { role: 'elite', web: [{ "_id": "55555555ffffff000010200b","name": 'web B' }] },
        { role: 'write', web: [{ "_id": "55555555ffffff000010200c","name": 'web C' }] },
        { role: 'write', web: [{ "_id": "55555555ffffff000010200a","name": 'web A' }] },
        { role: 'view',  web: [{ "_id": "55555555ffffff000010200a","name": 'web A' }] }
    ],
    q = [], i, j;

for (i = 0; i < p.length; i += 1) {
    j = 0;
    while (j < q.length && p[i].role !== q[j].role) {
        j += 1;
    }
    if (j < q.length) {
        q[j].web.push(p[i].web[0]);
    } else {
        q.push(p[i]);
    }
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(q));
```

Output:

```
[
    {"role":"elite","web":[{"_id":"55555555ffffff000010200a","name":"web A"},{"_id":"55555555ffffff000010200b","name":"web B"}]},
    {"role":"write","web":[{"_id":"55555555ffffff000010200c","name":"web C"},{"_id":"55555555ffffff000010200a","name":"web A"}]},
    {"role":"view","web":[{"_id":"55555555ffffff000010200a","name":"web A"}]}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
var output = {};

for (var k in p) {
  var item = p[k],
      role = item.role;

  if (output[role] == undefined) {
    output[role] = {role: role, web: []};
  }

  output[role].web.push(item.web.pop());
}

output = values(output);
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "role": "elite",
    "web": [
      {"_id": "55555555ffffff000010200a", "name": "web A"},
      {"_id": "55555555ffffff000010200b", "name": "web B"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "role": "write",
    "web": [
      {"_id": "55555555ffffff000010200c", "name": "web C"},
      {"_id": "55555555ffffff000010200a", "name": "web A"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "role": "view",
    "web": [
      {"_id": "55555555ffffff000010200a", "name": "web A"}
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: The `.push` results in nested arrays: `"view":[[{"_id":"55555555ffffff000010200a","name":"web A"}]]`

Comment: @Cerbrus I've missed that. Fixed.

Comment: The Final Object is different

Comment: Base keys like `elite`, `write`, `view` are required to put data into them. array with data (`_id`, `name`) is also required because you cannot have two `_id` keys in one object.

Comment: but i need an Object like kol's answer

Comment: @hsz Thanks again...what is values ?

Comment: @monkeyUser Its a function that gets values from an object and returns an array.